# Exact Target SQL find two values within a string

Tags: marketing-cloud, sqlserver

We have a value stored in a string in a table and we need to extract 2 values from it into 2 new fields.

The field name is linkname and it contains a value like 'VALUE1-VALUE2-52'.
We need to pull VALUE1 and VALUE2 out of the string and insert them into a second table.

I have tried using CHARINDEX but it doesn't work (as usual with SFMC i do not get any error message). Does anyone know how I can extract these 2 values using a query?

This should extract the first value but it fails:

```
select LEFT(linkname,CHARINDEX('-',linkname)-1) from mytable;
```

Anyone know how to extract the values? e.g - string value 'APPLE-ORANGES-52'. Return APPLE as VALUE1 and ORANGES as VALUE2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had passed success at using both Gaurav's ampscript approach and Arvind's SQL approach.

You can use **Case** statements to make Arvind's SQL query more fault tolerant.

```
SELECT 
 linkname
, CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-',linkname) > 0 THEN Substring(linkname,1,CHARINDEX('-', linkname)-1)
    ELSE linkname
  END as HEREISVALUE1
, CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-',linkname) > 0 THEN 
       CASE 
          WHEN CHARINDEX('-', Substring(linkname,CHARINDEX('-',linkname)+1,len(linkname))) > 0 THEN Substring(Substring(linkname,CHARINDEX('-',linkname)+1,len(linkname)),1, CHARINDEX('-', Substring(linkname,CHARINDEX('-',linkname)+1,len(linkname)))-1 )
          ELSE Substring(linkname,CHARINDEX('-',linkname)+1,len(linkname))
       END
    ELSE ''
  END as HEREISVALUE2
from [#TempTable]
```

**Input:**

```
|linkname        |
|:-------------- |
|APPLE-ORANGES-52|
|APPLE           |
|APPLE-ORANGE    |
|                |
```

**Output:**

```
|linkname        |HEREISVALUE1    |HEREISVALUE2    |
|:-------------- |:-------------- |:-------------- |
|APPLE-ORANGES-52|APPLE           |ORANGE          |
|APPLE           |APPLE           |                |
|APPLE-ORANGE    |APPLE           |ORANGE          |
|                |                |                |
```

Comment: Yeah that works really well - the error handling has meant we do not need to worry so much about records that do not comply.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than handling this in the query itself, you can use the [ampscript utility functions](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#Substring)

`IndexOf("Your String", "-")` will give you the indices of the hyphens
Then use those indices with
`Substring("Your String", "-")` to get the 2 relevant sub-strings

Based on the example above

`IndexOf("APPLE-ORANGES-52", "-")` will return 6

`SubString("APPLE-ORANGES-52", 0, 5)` will return Apple
`SubString("APPLE-ORANGES-52", 5+1)` will return Oranges-52

Run the same logic through `'Oranges-52'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL and a numbers (tally) helper table to split them out via a query activity

So something like this

```
SELECT 
email
, SUBSTRING('|' + Product + '|', n + 1, CHARINDEX('|', '|' + Product + '|', n + 1) - n - 1) AS product
FROM Nums
JOIN DE 
  ON (SUBSTRING('|' + Product + '|', n, 1 ) = '|' 
      AND n < LEN('|' +Product + '|')_
```

where Nums is a Numbers table with 1 column (n) that contains values from 1 to 10000 and DE is your DE and the Product is column you are splitting. Am using the pipe delimiter (|) but you can change the query to use your delimiter (-)