# Exact Target SQL comma separated values within a field

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sqlserver

We are having a field called - ‘VisitOverdueMailingList__c’ on the Account object populated with comma separated values. The field contains data in the following format (only for certain Accounts that satisfy certain conditions) :

```
Division, Business Unit, User Id, Email
Division, Business Unit, User Id, Email
Division, Business Unit, User Id, Email
…
```

The length of the Division is 2, Business Unit is 4, User Id is 18. The email length of course varies. So the input DE would be like :

[image]

This field gets synchronized into Marketing Cloud. The problem is this field can have different number of rows of data based on the Account on which it exists. I am trying to process this field in order to split those values into different column using SQL.

So the final Data Extension format that I want to achieve is as below :

[image: Data Extension after processing the comma separated values]

Taking reference from this stack exchange question : [Exact Target SQL find two values within a string](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104806/exact-target-sql-find-two-values-within-a-string/105812#105812) I am trying to construct query with 'Case' but then I am not sure how to handle the varying number of rows in this field.

Any Idea Or Solutions that I can try out on Marketing Cloud are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using a non SQL solution on MC I have resolved this. I have used AMPScript to process the rows. So I just added a column to the Source (input DE) with my Email ID then automate this email using Journey Builder. It is working :)