# SQL How to create a separate record for comma delimited values in within a field

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a table which have two fields ID and Source. Source col. have multiple emails with comma separated. I want to create a separate record for each email with same ID.

So data looks like this

```
ID .    Source  
1 .     a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com
```

I want to be looks like this;

```
ID .     Source
1.       a@a.com
1.       b@b.com
1.       c@c.com
```

I tried using "STRING_SPLIT" function but it didn't work, SFMC didn't recognize this function. Any other work around???

Comment: Just now tried query..
SELECT 
id, SUBSTRING(',' + email + ',', n + 1, CHARINDEX(',', ',' + email + ',', n + 1) - n - 1) AS email
FROM Numbers
JOIN stest 
  ON (SUBSTRING(',' + email + ',', n, 1 ) = ',' 
      AND n < LEN(',' +email + ','))
But again getting error "An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 2 of substring function."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CROSS APPLYs to unfurl the CSV list:

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE ListSubs
    ([list] varchar(13), [subscribers] varchar(500))
;

INSERT INTO ListSubs
    ([list], [subscribers])
VALUES
    ('1', 'a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com'),
    ('2', 'd@d.com,e@e.com,f@f.com')
;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
  a.list
  , a.subscribers
  , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, 1, ISNULL(p1 - 1, LEN(a.subscribers))) sub1
  , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p1 + 1, ISNULL(p2, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p1 - 1) sub2
  , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p2 + 1, ISNULL(p3, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p2 - 1) sub3
  , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p3 + 1, ISNULL(p4, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p3 - 1) sub4
  , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p4 + 1, ISNULL(p5, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p4 - 1) sub5
  , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p5 + 1, ISNULL(p6, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p5 - 1) sub6
  , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p6 + 1, ISNULL(p7, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p6 - 1) sub7
from ListSubs a
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers), 0)) b(p1)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p2 + 1), 0)) d(p3)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p3 + 1), 0)) e(p4)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p4 + 1), 0)) f(p5)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p5 + 1), 0)) g(p6)
CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p6 + 1), 0)) h(p7)
where isnull(a.subscribers,'') != ''
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87693/3/0).

If you want them in individual rows, then you could do this using the same method by splitting everything out in unions:

```
select 
  x.list
, x.sub
from (

    SELECT
    a.list
    , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, 1, ISNULL(p1 - 1, LEN(a.subscribers))) sub
    from ListSubs a
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers), 0)) b(p1)

    union 

    SELECT
    a.list
    , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p1 + 1, ISNULL(p2, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p1 - 1) sub
    from ListSubs a
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers), 0)) b(p1)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)

    union 

    SELECT
    a.list
    , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p2 + 1, ISNULL(p3, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p2 - 1) sub
    from ListSubs a
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers), 0)) b(p1)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p2 + 1), 0)) d(p3)

    union 

    SELECT
    a.list
    , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p3 + 1, ISNULL(p4, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p3 - 1) sub
    from ListSubs a
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers), 0)) b(p1)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p2 + 1), 0)) d(p3)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p3 + 1), 0)) e(p4)

    union 

    SELECT
    a.list
    , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p4 + 1, ISNULL(p5, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p4 - 1) sub
    from ListSubs a
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers), 0)) b(p1)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p2 + 1), 0)) d(p3)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p3 + 1), 0)) e(p4)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p4 + 1), 0)) f(p5)

    union 

    SELECT
    a.list
    , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p5 + 1, ISNULL(p6, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p5 - 1) sub
    from ListSubs a
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers), 0)) b(p1)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p2 + 1), 0)) d(p3)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p3 + 1), 0)) e(p4)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p4 + 1), 0)) f(p5)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p5 + 1), 0)) g(p6)

    union 

    SELECT
    a.list
    , SUBSTRING(a.subscribers, p6 + 1, ISNULL(p7, LEN(a.subscribers) + 1) - p6 - 1) sub
    from ListSubs a
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers), 0)) b(p1)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p1 + 1), 0)) c(p2)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p2 + 1), 0)) d(p3)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p3 + 1), 0)) e(p4)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p4 + 1), 0)) f(p5)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p5 + 1), 0)) g(p6)
    CROSS APPLY (select NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', a.subscribers, p6 + 1), 0)) h(p7)
) x 
where x.sub is not null
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/87693/14/0)

Comment: Thanks Adam. But this solution will create a seprate column for each email. I am looking for create a seprate row/record for each id. Any idea accomplish this ?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to figure out some implementation using SubString which Marketing CLoud does not seem to have a problem with.

For instance, this will get you the first email address:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([source], 1, CASE CHARINDEX(',', [source])
        WHEN 0
            THEN LEN([source])
        ELSE CHARINDEX(',', [source]) - 1
        END) AS Email
FROM _table
```

Can you expand upon that to fit your needs?

Implementations are really limited without user functions, variables, temp tables which are not supported based upon the documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you Mike. I tried the below query...
SELECT id, 
SUBSTRING(source, 1, CASE CHARINDEX(',', source)
        WHEN 0
            THEN LEN(source)
        ELSE CHARINDEX(',', source) - 1
        END) AS Email
FROM stest

But this query only brings 1 email and finish. How do i split all email?

Comment: Anyone please.. ????

Comment: Do you have a set number of emails per row or is it variable?

I am having difficulty thinking of an exact implementation due to the marketing cloud sql limitations.

Here is another question and an answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190776/exact-target-sql-comma-separated-values-within-a-field?rq=1

Comment: Well their is no set number of emails per row. It can be 1, it can be 5. But so far I found not more than 5 emails. So lets assume If I will have max 5 emails, then what's the solution.
Thanks again Mike.