# Splitting CONCAT data in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sql, automationstudio, email-studio

We are receiving data from our Sales Cloud instance via MCC connector, and in one of the fields tied to a personAccount - "Agent_Names" - we have multiple string values (i.e.support agents' names) concatenated / divided with a comma ",". For example, John Smith,John Doe,Mike Mikeson,...  We would need to work with this data in Marketing Cloud in 2 ways:

1. Directly in email body (Email Studio/Content Builder) where we would need to e.g. list the names of all support agents the customer can contact through AMPscrip, and
2. In Automation Studio - where we would need to either divide this data across other fields in a data extension (SSJS?) or do some filtering based on such data.

What are your suggestions for these 2 use case, other than going to our Sales Cloud team and asking for better data :).
Thanks

Comment: a) buildRowSetFromString()AMPScript function https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm

b) splitting in SQL via CROSS APPLY as shown here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253179/sql-how-to-create-a-separate-record-for-comma-delimited-values-in-within-a-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JonasLamberty stated in his comment, you would want to do **[BuildRowsetFromString()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm)** in AMPscript to be able to use it in an email.

**BuildRowsetFromString():**

```ampscript
SET @myDelimitedField = "first,second,third"

SET @rows = BuildRowsetFromString(@myDelimitedField,",")

FOR @i=1 TO Rowcount(@rows) DO
  SET @myValue = Field(Row(@rows,@i),1)
NEXT @i
```

In SQL you have a couple options, including **[CROSS APPLY](https://gortonington.com/splitting-a-delimited-string-field-in-sql-query/)** as @JonasLamberty said.

**CROSS APPLY:**

```sql
SELECT    p.Email
        , p.FieldA
        , c.FieldB
FROM [testParse] p
CROSS APPLY (
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB1
    UNION ALL
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB2
    UNION ALL
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB3
    UNION ALL
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB4
    UNION ALL
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[5]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB5
    UNION ALL
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[6]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB6
    UNION ALL
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[7]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB7
    UNION ALL
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[8]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB8
    UNION ALL
    Select  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(p.FieldB,',','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[9]','nvarchar(max)') as FieldB9
) c (FieldB)
WHERE ISNULL(c.FieldB,'') <> ''
```

and also turning the whole delimited string into **[XML and using the Value() function](https://gortonington.com/selecting-and-displaying-nodes-in-sql-from-delimited-strings/)**.

```sql
SELECT pkey,
CAST('<x>' + REPLACE('a|b|c|d','|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[1]','nvarchar(max)') as firstNode,
CAST('<x>' + REPLACE('a|b|c|d','|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') as secondNode,
CAST('<x>' + REPLACE('a|b|c|d','|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)') as thirdNode,
CAST('<x>' + REPLACE('a|b|c|d','|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)') as fourthNode
FROM [myDE]
```

Which will output each part of the string up to 4 values - you can adjust the number of nodes to include the number of things inside of the field.

Then also inside of SSJS you can use **[Split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)** to turn the string into an array and then use index notation to pull the different values.

```javascript
var myString = 'first,second,third'
var myArr = myString.Split(',');
//["first","second","third"]

var val1 = myArr[0]
//first

var val2 = myArr[1]
//second

var val3 = myArr[2]
//third
```