# Split into different rows using SSJS or Query or whatever

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, sql

I'm totally lost spliting my dataset.
The dataset looks like below.

[image]

What I want to is split 'Field 3' and build exact like under picture.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this requirement?
If so, please give me some direction...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ampscript: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/buildrowsetfromstring.html  / 
SQL:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253179/sql-how-to-create-a-separate-record-for-comma-delimited-values-in-within-a-field

Answer (score 0):

The common concept to do this is that you would need to split the "field 3" column values by `,` character and hence insert a new row to a new DE for each element.

The following code here is a sample code to do that in SSJS. It might need to be modified/enhanced to fit with your actual needs.

```JavaScript
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
var de1CustKey = "Your original DE customer key";

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = ["Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3"];
var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtensionObject["+ de1CustKey +"]", cols);

var rowcount = data.Results.length;
if (rowcount > 0) {
    for (var i=0; i < rowcount; i++) {
        var field3Value = data.Results[i].Properties[2].Value;
        var elements = field3Value.split(",");
        if (elements.length > 0) {
            for (var n=0; n < elements.length; n++) {
                Platform.Function.InsertData("Your split DE 2 name", ["Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3"], [data.Results[i].Properties[0].Value, data.Results[i].Properties[1].Value, elements[n]]);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```